# How may I set my app as preferred app in the app, not in the application manager?

Tags: android, default

I am creating an image viewer, and I want add an entry to "Hey my dear user, please set this app as your default image viewer" in my app.

So, I need my app has `SET_PREFERRED_APPLICATIONS` permission granted. But sadly, as the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SET_PREFERRED_APPLICATIONS) said, this field is deprecated and no longer useful, not effective at all when I add `<user-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_PERFERRED_APPLICATIONS" />` to the `AndroidMenifest.xml`.

But the doc doesn't point out the alternative. Could anybody tell me how may I make that? TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of deprecating that permission may have been to give the user full control. They will have the option of setting your app as a preferred one themselves and you can, of course, encourage them to do so, e.g. in the welcome screen if you have one. I don't think you can do what you're looking for but wouldn't worry about that. If your app does what it should well, users will set it as the preferred one.

Comment: Perhaps. Try putting yourself in your user's shoes, for a while, however: I think a consistent way to set preferred apps (and consistent way of how things work) has a positive effect in the end; they feel comfortable with their device knowing it behaves predictably. And like I said, they do have a way of preferring your app if they so desire.